# going reverse in a for loop?

Tags: c++, string, gcc, for-loop

Basically i got this for loop and i want the number inputed (eg. 123) to be printed out in reverse, so "321". 
so far it works fine and prints out the correct order when the for loop is

```
for(i = 0; i<len ; i++)
```

but i get an error when i try to print it in reverse?. Whats going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void cnvrter(char *number);

int main(){
    char number[80];
    printf("enter a number ");
    gets(number);
    cnvrter(number);

    return 0;
}

void cnvrter(char *number){
    char tmp[80];
    int i = 0,len = 0;
    int cnvrtd_digit = 0;
    len = strlen(number);
    printf("\nsize of input %d\n",len);
    for(i = len; i>len ; i--){
        if ( ( number[i] >= '0' ) && ( number[i]<='9' ) ){
            tmp[0] = number[i];
            sscanf(tmp,"%d",&cnvrtd_digit);

        }
        printf("%d\n",cnvrtd_digit);
    }
}
```

Comment: error as in it compiles but crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your `for` loop again:

```
for(i = len; i>len ; i--){
```

You're doing `i=len`, and then testing for `i>len` -- unless something goes seriously wrong in the assignment, that's never going to be true...

By the way, though it's not related, you shouldn't be using `gets`, even in a program like this that you never intend to put to serious use.

Comment: hmmm when i use for(i = len; i>=0 ; i--) i get 0321 printed out. why does this 0 appeare?

Comment: In C and C++, array indices start at 0, so for a string with a length of 3, the largest valid index is 2.

Comment: You should use i=len-1, not i=len.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit `for`-loop to reverse a string in C++. You could use `std::reverse()` or `str.rbegin(), str.rend()`.

```
// -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
// $ g++ *.cc && (echo 'abc1d23e->١<-_ f999fff' | ./a.out)
#include <algorithm>  // remove_copy_if
#include <functional> // not1
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>   // ostream_iterator
#include <string>

int main() {
  using namespace std;

  cout << "enter a number " << flush;               // print prompt
  string str; cin >> str;                           // read until first space
  cout << "\nsize of input " << str.size() << endl;

  remove_copy_if(
      str.rbegin(), str.rend(),                     // traverse in reverse order
      ostream_iterator<string::value_type>(cout, "\n"), // copy to stdout
                                                        // separated by newline
      not1(ptr_fun((int (*)(int))isdigit)));        // remove non-digits
}
```

Run it:

```
$ g++ *.cc && (echo 'abc1d23e->١<-_ f999fff' | ./a.out)
enter a number 
size of input 15
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You never advance the index on `tmp`, and you never null-terminate it.